# PHP exec Java on Windows produces no output

Tags: php, exec

I've read through a lot of similar SO questions about my issue, none seem to have my issue. If it's relevant, I'm running PHP 5.3.8 on Apache 2.2 and PHP exec() runs as `nt authority\system`

```
$cmd = "java -version";
$res = exec($cmd, $output, $return);

var_dump($res, $output, $return);
```

Produces:

```
string '' (length=0)

array
    empty

int 0
```

`$return` being 0 hints that this was successful. Interestingly, if I run:

```
$cmd = "java -version 2> response";
```

A file is created with the expected output:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

So my question: Why is `$output` not getting populated?

**Comment update**

Result of `$res = exec("dir c:", $output, $return);`

```
string '               2 Dir(s)  335,636,791,296 bytes free' (length=51)

array
    0 => string ' Volume in drive C is Local Disk' (length=32)
    1 => string ' Volume Serial Number is D87C-E25C' (length=34)
    2 => string '' (length=0)
    ...
    12 => string '               5 File(s)          1,158 bytes' (length=45)
    13 => string '               2 Dir(s)  335,636,791,296 bytes free' (length=51)

int 0
```

Comment: please check my updated answer, hope it will fix it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not an "answer" - what I ended up doing was to redirect all output to STDOUT and check `$return` for 0.

This may be related to [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41874), even though I'm running 5.3 it seems to match my scenario

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
$output = `java -version 2>&1`
```

watch for the backticks around the command, it serves exactly as shell command

2>&1 should redirect error to stdout since java by default use stderror !

Comment: Tried that $output is just `null`

Comment: can you try something like `dir c:\`

Comment: edited main question with output - all good - no issues with execution

Answer (score 0):

You seem to compare apples with oranges as in second example you redirect stderr stream while you do not do that in first case. I suggest to always redirect stderr to stdout while using calls like `exec` otherwise you will lose this output

Comment: But why is output going to stderr? According to PHP the command executed successfully - note `$return = 0`